How do I run bazel with a proxy
I'm trying to build a simple project with Bazel. Unfortunately, I don't get through the corporate proxy on a Windows 10 machine.
λ bazel build //:my-lib                                                                                                                                                
ERROR: Error computing the main repository mapping: Error accessing registry https://bcr.bazel.build/: Failed to fetch registry file https://bcr.bazel.build/modules/platforms/0.0.9/
MODULE.bazel: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"                                                                             
Computing main repo mapping:                                                                                                                                                         

                                                                                                                                                                                 

I have set HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY and NO_PROXY with values of the format
HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:pwssword@proxy.name:port/
HTTP_PROXY=http://username:pwssword@proxy.name:port/
NO_PROXY=localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*, some more

I'm sure they are OK, since a number of other tools pick this up and are working fine.
According to the docs, Bazel should just pick this up: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.29.1/external.html#using-proxies
Any ideas to get this working?
WORKSPACE file
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG = "4.3"
RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA = "6274687f6fc5783b589f56a2f1ed60de3ce1f99bc4e8f9edef3de43bdf7c6e74"

http_archive(
    name = "rules_jvm_external",
    sha256 = RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA,
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-%s" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/%s.zip" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
)

load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.0",
        "jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1",
        "com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.3",
        "org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.20",
        "org.checkerframework:checker-qual:3.12.0",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
    ],
)

BUILD file
java_library(
    name = "my-lib",
    srcs = glob(["my-lib/src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["my-lib/src/main/resources/**"]),
    deps = [
        "@maven//_com_fasterxml_jackson_core_jackson_annotations",
        "@maven//_jakarta_annotation_jakarta_annotation_api",
    ],
)


Maybe there is something on your environment variables that is used accidentally by Bazel and that ignores the proxy variables. Can you try to remove local installed maven form your environment varialbe, or whatever those rules use to fetch maven dependencies?
